# How can I use PyTorch 2.2 with Google Colab TPUs?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, jax

I'm having trouble getting PyTorch 2.2 running with TPUs on Google Colab. I'm getting an error about a JAX bug, but I'm confused about this because I'm not doing anything with JAX.

My setup process is very simple:

```
!pip install torch~=2.2.0 torch_xla[tpu]~=2.2.0 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html
```

And then

```
import torch
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
```

which gives the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/__init__.py:27: UserWarning: cloud_tpu_init failed: KeyError('')
 This a JAX bug; please report an issue at https://github.com/google/jax/issues
  _warn(f"cloud_tpu_init failed: {repr(exc)}\n This a JAX bug; please report "
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py:441: UserWarning: torch.utils._pytree._register_pytree_node is deprecated. Please use torch.utils._pytree.register_pytree_node instead.
  _torch_pytree._register_pytree_node(
```

Then trying

```
t1 = torch.tensor(100, device=xm.xla_device())
t2 = torch.tensor(200, device=xm.xla_device())
print(t1 + t2)
```

gives the error

```
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch_xla/runtime.py in xla_device(n, devkind)
    121 
    122   if n is None:
--> 123     return torch.device(torch_xla._XLAC._xla_get_default_device())
    124 
    125   devices = xm.get_xla_supported_devices(devkind=devkind)

RuntimeError: Bad StatusOr access: UNKNOWN: TPU initialization failed: No ba16c7433 device found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colab currently only provides an older generation of TPUs which is not compatible with recent JAX or PyTorch releases. It’s possible that may change in the future, but I don’t know of any official timeline of when that might happen. In the meantime, you can access recent-generation TPUs via Kaggle or Google Cloud.